# Is world an output of imagination?

Tags: creation

Is world is just an output of imagination? and all the people (family, friends) are an output of imagination and not real?
If yes, how it happens, when and why this imagination occurs.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36045/16530

Comment: Unless you're turiya it's maya loka, in turiya we gain our aryan divine powers back, a matrix created by jew villains, equal to black agents who attack Neo, to stop him from coming back to true reality(brahman), and enslaved, trapped in virtual reality they want him to see, enact, who cheat us, write false version of everything and replace it with true version.

Comment: Various scriptures indeed say that world is the output of mind .. once the mind is destroyed so is the world.

Comment: This is a type of idealism that some older and lesser known Advaita and Buddhist philosophies espoused. It is not the unreality of the world as taught by Sankara. See https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey

Answer (score 1):

> Is world an output of imagination?

**No, the world is real and a creation of Brahman for the Jivas to experience their karma, which is also real.**

[Ramanujacharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanuja) says in his [commentary](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48008.htm) on the Brahma Sutras about the idea of the world being unreal:

> This entire theory rests on a fictitious foundation of altogether hollow and vicious arguments, incapable of being stated in definite logical alternatives, and devised by men who are destitute of those particular qualities which cause individuals to be chosen by the Supreme Person revealed in the Upanishads; whose intellects are darkened by the impression of beginningless evil; and who thus have no insight into the nature of words and sentences, into the real purport conveyed by them, and into the procedure of sound argumentation, with all its methods depending on perception and the other instruments of right knowledge. The theory therefore must needs be rejected by all those who, through texts, perception and the other means of knowledge--assisted by sound reasoning--have an insight into the true nature of things.